# How should I use Cisco ASA 5510 and Catalyst 3550 together

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, cisco-asa, cisco-catalyst

So I took on a project at my job moving four separate networks into one Colo center.

Currently I broken everything down from the four networks into 4 VLANS on the ASA 5510. Each are assigned IPs with a /24 subnet.

I have set up port e0/1 on the ASA 5510 with an IP of 172.20.0.1 and have that sent to fa0/48 on the 3550 using IP address 172.20.0.3.

I have been able to ping both interfaces and I have been able to set up a route from the ASA to the internet.

I am not sure where to go from here.

Here is the show run for the ASA 5510

```
    mdc-fw01# show run
: Saved
:
ASA Version 9.1(5)
!
hostname mdc-fw01
domain-name mdcommerce.local
enable password F7aoYryYQMUHhnCL encrypted
names
!
interface Ethernet0/0
nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 216.176.***.*** 255.255.255.240
!
interface Ethernet0/1
 duplex full
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 172.20.0.1 255.255.255.248
!
interface Ethernet0/1.1
 vlan 15
 nameif MDCommerce
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.15.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet0/1.2
 vlan 20
 nameif Camber
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet0/1.3
 vlan 10
 nameif ASP
 security-level 100
 ip address 10.0.2.254 255.255.255.0
! 
interface Ethernet0/1.4
 vlan 201
 nameif HSSI
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.201.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Ethernet0/2
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface Ethernet0/3
 shutdown
 no nameif
 no security-level
 no ip address
!
interface Management0/0
 management-only
 nameif management
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
ftp mode passive
clock timezone PST -8
clock summer-time PDT recurring
dns domain-lookup outside
dns domain-lookup inside
dns server-group DefaultDNS
 name-server 216.176.***.***
 name-server 216.176.***.***
domain-name mdcommerce.local
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
object network obj_any
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
pager lines 24
logging enable
logging asdm informational
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
mtu MDCommerce 1500
mtu Camber 1500
mtu ASP 1500
mtu HSSI 1500
mtu management 1500
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
!
object network obj_any
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface
!
router ospf 1
 log-adj-changes
!
route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 216.176.***.*** 1
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat        0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect   0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
aaa authentication ssh console LOCAL
http server enable
http 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 management
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart     warmstart
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint0
 enrollment terminal
 subject-name CN=mdc-fw01
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpool policy
telnet timeout 5
no ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 outside
ssh 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 management
ssh timeout 5
ssh version 2
 ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0
dhcpd address 192.168.1.2-192.168.1.254 management
dhcpd enable management
!
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
username admin password XuyJjvRO952UKR8l encrypted
!
!
prompt hostname context
no call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:914f8c23591806b703df3d5c7ad203c6
: end
```

And here is my show run from my Cisco 3550

```
mdc-sw01>enable
mdc-sw01#show run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 3875 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname mdc-sw01
!
!
no aaa new-model
ip subnet-zero
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
 description HSSI Domain Controller
 switchport access vlan 201
 switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
 description Camber Domain Controller
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
 description ASP Domain Controller
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
 description Backup Server Ubuntu
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
 description MDCommerce Domain Controller
 switchport access vlan 15
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/48
 no switchport
 ip address 172.20.0.3 255.255.255.248
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no switchport
 no ip address
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 switchport mode dynamic desirable
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan15
 ip address 192.168.15.1 255.255.255.0
!
ip default-gateway 172.20.0.1
ip classless
ip http server
ip http secure-server
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
line vty 5 15
!
end
```

I have no clue what to do from this point. Any suggestions or help would be extremely appriciated.

Comment: What is the difference between what you have and what you want to have?

Comment: Well this is what I have... obviously lol. What I am wanting is this. I have the four networks that I would like to set up under the 3550 and use the ASA 5510 only to inspect and route traffic, assign VPNs, etc. 

Each network also has at least 6 servers in which all of our users , who reside on the Camber & MDCommerces networks/vlans need full user access to everything on the 3550, all devices, vlans, etc. As well as our S2S satellite offices. 

I hope that makes sense. I know it's a PITA.

Comment: What I ended up doing to make my life easier was created an OSPF area between the two devices. We had a lot of NATing that had to be done so I figured that this was the easiest way to kill two birds with one stone... so to speak. Since I was using an OSPF area, all of my NAT statements would be added automatically. From that point all I had to do was add an access-list for traffic and I was done.